# How to license software that implements a well-documented algorithm, but which does not borrow source from the official library?

Tags: gpl, software, github

I have implemented an RSYNC library based on the 
[technical report](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/) by Andrew Tridgell and Paul Mackerras.  The library implementation does not borrow code from the official RSYNC library and does not conform to the official API.  I would like to release my library as free software on GitHub.

The RSYNC library itself is released under the GNU GPL, but as I am not using or modifying the library's source, I am not sure how to license my own library.  What are my licensing options, if any?  How do I attribute the technical report?

Comment: Have you ever looked at the official library's source code?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul  I have not.  The implementation is based entirely on the referenced technical report.

Comment: According to the current status of the Google vs Oracle lawsuit, the "structure, sequence and organisation" of an API is a copyrighted work and therefore copying the RSYNC API is copyright infringement. Google tried to appeal the appeal but the supreme court refused a few months ago. I'm not sure if there will be further developments.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Good point. However, in this case, my library does not conform to the official API. The question has been edited.  Thank you.

Comment: @user2644 then in that case you should be perfectly fine. Copyright intentionally does not apply to "functionality", it only applies to "creative" things and actively encourages copying of everything else. Only patents protect functionality, and those expire orders of magnitude sooner than copyright. I dunno if there are patents applying to rsync? Probably not.

Comment: Also another thing to keep in mind is for RSYNC to bring a successful lawsuit against you they need to prove that your actions harmed them in some way. That was easy for Oracle vs Google, since Google enquired about and then refused to pay a royalty fee for every android phone ever sold. But the rights to rsync are not available at a commercial rate. They could probably stop you from releasing your code but getting you to pay damages would be difficult.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you have never looked at the source code, and ONLY looked at:

- The API
- The [no-code very high-level description](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/node3.html) of the synchronization algorithm

then you are free to release your implementation under any license you want.

Just like SAMBA checked the API and algorithms of CIFS and released their software under the license they wanted.

Or at least, that was the common point of view until the Google vs Oracle lawsuit, where the "structure, sequence and organisation" of an API got considered a copyrighted work and therefore copying the RSYNC API would be copyright infringement. Google tried to appeal the appeal but the supreme court refused a few months ago. I'm not sure if there will be further developments, but this decision is a huge loss for interoperability and innovation so we can only hope that the judiciary will realize their mistake. (Thanks Abhi for the info)

You don't *have* to attribute the technical report (except if you pasted significant parts of it inside your code or documentation), but an URL is nice and safe to paste before each relevant algorithm implementation.

In case you had seen the source code, the matter would not be so clear-cut, see some real-world examples with various outcomes at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design#Case_law.

Comment: "You don't have to attribute the technical report." - depends how much of it he quoted in comments inside his code, in documentation and so on. It might be mandatory, and for sure it's both safer and nicer to attribute it. Also, OP does not ask if, but how to attribute it.

Comment: @Mołot: Thanks! Is it better now?

Comment: You already had my upvote but yes, I think it now covers it perfectly.

Comment: Are you implying that looking at source code at some point is enough that any software you write that does similar things is derivative work? I don't think it's relevant whether you looked at, glanced over or extensively studied some code, as long as your own code isn't obviously based on that code.

Comment: @kapep: A bit off-topic, but I added the last paragraph about that, thanks!

Comment: @kapep no. But it will be far easier to *prove* it's not if you've never seen the code.

Comment: According to the current status of the Google vs Oracle lawsuit, the "structure, sequence and organisation" of an API is a copyrighted work and therefore copying the RSYNC API is copyright infringement. Google tried to appeal the appeal but the supreme court refused a few months ago. I'm not sure if there will be further developments.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Thanks! I re-use your comment per CC-BY-SA-3.0 ;-)

Comment: @AbhiBeckert there will be further developments, because the fair use case is yet to be heard. Also, in the exact language of the appeals, "the declaring code and the structure, sequence, and organization of the API packages are entitled to copyright protection". This does not necessarily mean that any API is copyright protected, but that the structure of the API's of Java's stdlib as a whole is protected. What that all means is still in the open of course.

Comment: @Martijn further developments will depend on wether or not it settles out of court just like pretty much every other copyright lawsuit.